# flac: Output to stdout (-c) breaks, same command written to file (-o) works

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, alsa, flac

I am trying to record audio using `arecord`, encode it to .flac using the `flac` tool, and then pipe it through a couple more processes (gzip, gpg, but irrelevant here).

If I write the result from `flac` to file using the `-o` parameter, everything works fine:

```
arecord -t raw -f S16_LE -r16000 -d 10 -D sysdefault:CARD=1 | flac - -f --endian little --sign signed --channels 1 --bps 16 --sample-rate 16000 -o test.flac
```

If I instead use the `-c` parameter and redirect the output to a file:

```
arecord -t raw -f S16_LE -r16000 -d 10 -D sysdefault:CARD=1 | flac - -f --endian little --sign signed --channels 1 --bps 16 --sample-rate 16000 -c > test.flac
```

...the resulting file plays back fine (the sound works), but VLC does not display a length for the audio recording, and audacity starts an import process with a steadily increasing ETA of several hours and hangs on cancel.

The only difference between both commands is `-o test.flac` vs `-c > test.flac`. Why does this break the file?

If it makes a difference: flac 1.3.2, arecord 1.1.3, running on latest raspbian on a Pi3 with USB microphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't calculate the final length through pipe, so it can't write it to the header of flac. It doesn't break the file, it saves as a livestream, which you shouldn't know when will be the end, and the header is on the beginning of the file.