# Add missing length headers to flac file created by streaming

Tags: flac

As I have [recently learned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400148/257158), flac files created by piping encoded flac data to STDOUT are missing certain pieces of metadata, in particular information about the length of the recording.

**Is it possible to retroactively add this data *without decoding to wav and re-encoding the data*** (the data is [too large for a wav file](https://superuser.com/questions/1261530/arecord-create-large-7-days-audio-recording), and flac will gladly decode to wav, but then throw an error and refuse to re-encode to flac afterwards)? I know the exact length of the recording, if this is helpful.

---

For the curious: This is what happens when I decode and re-encode a 7 day audio recording from flac to wav and back.

```
flac --decode test.flac 

flac 1.3.1, Copyright (C) 2000-2009  Josh Coalson, 2011-2014  Xiph.Org Foundation
flac comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are
welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  Type `flac' for details.

test.flac: WARNING, cannot check MD5 signature since it was unset in the STREAMINFO
done         
test.flac: ERROR: stream is too big to fit in a single WAVE file
```

Now I have a wav file that plays fine in VLC and contains proper length information. Trying to re-encode:

```
flac test.wav --best --output-name="test2.flac"

flac 1.3.1, Copyright (C) 2000-2009  Josh Coalson, 2011-2014  Xiph.Org Foundation
flac comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are
welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  Type `flac' for details.

test.wav: ERROR: 'data' chunk has size of 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to re-encode the whole thing using sox:

```
sox test.flac test_full.flac --show-progress
```

This will take the full recording, decode it, and re-encode it back to flac. Highly inefficient, but gets the job done. If there is a nicer solution that avoide the 10 minute encoding process, feel free to add another answer and I will accept that one instead.